# How do I update a CustomUser value via UpdateView using a hidden logic

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I've spent several hours on this and I'm not able to see any signs as to why the change on the flag is not getting through.
Please note the change form already works for all exposed fields, i.e. the user can go in and change the name or country already and it will get saved after clicking on update profile.
What I'm now trying to do is to also change the confirmed_email flag to True (but without telling or letting the user  see it) whenever the client makes an update to the form.
To do this I check if the user was logged in using Linkedin (or any Social account for that matter) via something along the lines of ""if user.social_auth.exists()"". That said, it's not that i can't fulfill this function, it's that even when i use a silly condition that i know it's true the field "email_confirmed" will still NOT change to True in the back-end.

Thanks so much in advance. I appreciate your time.
PS. I'm a noob with Django but loving it.

Models.py

```
    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
            id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
            email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
            email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
            country = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=COUNTRY, null=True, blank=False)
            first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")
            last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")
```

Views.py

```
    class SignUpView(CreateView):
        form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
        template_name = 'signup.html'
        ...
    
    class UpdateProfileView(UpdateView): 
        form_class = CustomUserChangeForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
        template_name = 'update_profile.html'
        def get_object(self, queryset=None):
          return self.request.user
```

Forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
    from .models import CustomUser
    
    class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
        class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
            model = CustomUser
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name','country',) 
    
    class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
        password = None
        class Meta:
            model = CustomUser
            fields = ('first_name', 'last_name','country',)

update_profile.html
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h2>Update Profile</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
  </form>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

```
My main attempt was to adding another leg in the view (see def ChangeActiveStatus below).
```

```
class UpdateProfileView(UpdateView): 
    form_class = CustomUserChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'update_profile.html'
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
      return self.request.user
    def ChangeActiveStatus(request):
      if request.method == "POST":
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        if form.is_valid() and user.social_auth.exists() == True:
          user.email_confirmed = True
          form.save()
        else:
          form = form()
      return render(request, 'login', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a solution via models.py instead, basically bypassing the need to save any changes on one of the fields through the views, i.e. this is the logic, which will be triggered every time the client changes something in their profile.

```
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                CustomUser.objects.latest('id').id   
            except:
            ...
            ...


                if self.is_active == True and self.email_verified == False:
                    self.email_verified = True
                super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're setting the `email_confirmed = True` on `user` and not `form.instance`. You could also save the `user` instance rather than calling `form.save()`.

```
  form = self.form_class()
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and user.social_auth.exists():
      user = form.save(commit=False)
      user.email_confirmed = True
      user.save()
  return render(request, 'login', {'form':form})
```

Or

```
  form = self.form_class()
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and user.social_auth.exists():
      form.instance.email_confirmed = True
      form.save()
  return render(request, 'login', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Thank you @schillingt for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, i've tried both of your suggestions without success. I don't even see any errors in the console it just does not get updated. I also tested a simpler condition (such as checking for the form validity) and it also did not work. Below what I used: Just to be sure you were advising on including your code right below 'def ChangeActiveStatus(request):' correct?